# Set color of object (Autodesk forge)

Tags: autodesk-forge

This works on model which don't have any color:

```
 this.viewer.setThemingColor(node, red, this.model);
```

But not on model with objects which have a color.

In the [docs](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v6/reference/javascript/guiviewer3d/#setthemingcolor-dbid-color-model) you can read:

> Highlight an object with a theming color that is **blended** with the
>   original object’s material.

Blended? What does it mean? How do I set a color to an object if it already has a color?

P.S:
Typescript typedefinition to the Viewer would really be helpfull.

**Update**

Think it has something to do with the type of object.

I have run both `isolate` and `setThemingColor` (red) on the same items.

In the screenshot below, the red door in lower right corner is selected:
[image: Red door selected]

It has a "material" heading.

In this screenshot the door next to it (turquoise) is selected. It's missing the material heading.

[image]

Do I need to "apply" material or something to make it change color?

Answer (score 0):

Did you supply a `THREE.Vector4` object as color or the second argument? Just dug into the code and it wasn't any type check logic and would lead to your error if the wrong type is given. Also make sure you put in the right model object as the third argument, otherwise the render won't know which model to apply the colors when you have multiple models.

You can details about the usage of this method below:
https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v6/reference/javascript/viewer3d/#setthemingcolor-dbid-color-model

Edit:
If the component is lacking a material pls see here on how to add a custom one: https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/using-dynamic-texture-inside-custom-shaders

PS: We are working on TypeScript definitions for Viewer and Forge SDK and they could be released soon. Stay tuned!

Comment: Yes I supply a THREE.Vector4 color. As I said, it works on models which don't have any color set to the objects (they are all grey). But it's not working on objects which have a color from the beginning. There's no function I need to run before to "override" the original color?

Comment: No there isn’t, by blended and as the name of the function suggests it adds a secondary(theming) color to your objects, keeping its original color as the primary. Can you show me the model and your code if possible (like a quick demo on jsfiddle)? Alternatively you can try set the material of the model (see [here](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/forge-viewer-custom-shaders-part-1)). Before that you might also want to check if you are on [Viewer v6](https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/6.*/viewer3D.min.js) just so we won’t let bugs from the old times get in our way

Comment: See here on how to apply custom material: https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/using-dynamic-texture-inside-custom-shaders